# Construct JSON_ARRAY with conditional second object

Tags: mysql, json

I have a simple sample table:

| f1 | f2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

I want to create a JSON array of each line - BUT, I do not want to include the second object if its value is 3.

So I would like the results to be:

```
[{'num',1},{'num',2}]
[{'num',1}]
```

If I try this:

```
select JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('num',f1),
                if(f2<>3,JSON_OBJECT('num',f2),JSON_OBJECT())                     
                  ) from sample_table;
```

its close, but it places an empty object instead of nothing:

```
[{"num": 1}, {"num": 2}]
[{"num": 1}, {}]
```

Is there a better way to handle?
Else, I suppose a 2nd option, is there an easy way to remove empty objects after the fact (like a wrapper around the JSON_ARRAY function)

I suppose if I place the IF at the start, that can work.. but is there a slicker way?

```
select if(f2<>3, JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('num',f1),JSON_OBJECT('num',f2)),
                        JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('num',f1))                     
                  ) from sample_table;
```

Comment: I ask about a slicker way, since the actual use case has many fields in the object and i'd hate to have to list out all of them a third time due to having separate JSON_ARRAY calls

Comment: I don't think there's a much better way. I tested whether using `NULL` as an argument would leave out that element, but it results in `null` in the array.

Comment: JSON_ARRAY includes any value into the final array, even NULL. I'd recommend you to use string functions and build an array with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want using [`JSON_ARRAY_APPEND`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-array-append), taking advantage of the fact that:

> Pairs for which the path does not identify any value in the JSON document are ignored

and using a dummy path when you don't want to add the object to the array.

```sql
select JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(
  "[]",
  '$',
  JSON_OBJECT('num',f1),
  CASE WHEN f2<>3 THEN '$' ELSE '$.dummy' END, 
  JSON_OBJECT('num',f2)
) AS result
FROM sample_table;
```

Output for your sample data:

| result |
| --- |
| [{"num": 1}, {"num": 2}] |
| [{"num": 1}] |

Demo on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kg3gLo7CBecjMaeqpMujHc/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT( '[',
               CONCAT_WS( ',',
                          JSON_OBJECT('num',f1),
                          CASE WHEN f2<>3 THEN JSON_OBJECT('num',f2) END
                          ),
               ']'
               )
FROM sample_table
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/1SJR2xkU

Comment: thanks.. but for my case, I'm sticking with the JSON functions where possible